# add button to TreeNode

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treenode

Good day.
There is a custom control that adds a button to each Node

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles

Public Class CustomTreeView
    Inherits TreeView

    Private buttonRect As New Rectangle(80, 2, 50, 26)
    Private ReadOnly stringFormat As StringFormat

    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)

        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText
        ShowLines = False
        FullRowSelect = True
        ItemHeight = 30

        stringFormat = New StringFormat With {
            .Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
            .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        }
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawNode(ByVal e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor), e.Bounds, stringFormat)
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, New Rectangle(e.Node.Bounds.Location + New Size(buttonRect.Location), buttonRect.Size), "btn", Me.Font, True, If(e.Node.Tag IsNot Nothing, CType(e.Node.Tag, PushButtonState), PushButtonState.Normal))
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNodeMouseClick(ByVal e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs)
        Select Case e.Node.Tag
            Case Nothing, Is <> PushButtonState.Pressed
                Return
        End Select
        e.Node.Tag = PushButtonState.Normal
        MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text & " clicked")
        ' force redraw
        e.Node.Text = e.Node.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim tnode As TreeNode = GetNodeAt(e.Location)
        If tnode Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim btnRectAbsolute As New Rectangle(tnode.Bounds.Location + New Size(buttonRect.Location), buttonRect.Size)
        If btnRectAbsolute.Contains(e.Location) Then
            tnode.Tag = PushButtonState.Pressed
            tnode.Text = tnode.Text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

tell me how you can display the button only to the first (main) nod?
And how, when you click on this button, not display a message, but let's say call some procedure?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in button tree node. But you can create a custom tree node having a button yourself. This custom tree node inherits from `TreeNode`. To improve extensibility, we declare an interface for tree nodes having a `DrawNode` method:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles

Public Interface ICustomDrawTreeNode
    Sub DrawNode(ByVal e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs, buttonState As PushButtonState)
End Interface
```

We also create a module containing some settings used in the custom tree view and in the custom tree node

```
Module Settings
    Public ReadOnly ButtonRect As New Rectangle(80, 2, 50, 26)

    Public ReadOnly TextStringFormat = New StringFormat() With {
        .Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
        .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        .FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip Or StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox Or StringFormatFlags.LineLimit
    }

End Module
```

We can then implement a button node like this

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles

Public Class ButtonTreeNode
    Inherits TreeNode
    Implements ICustomDrawTreeNode

    Private ReadOnly buttonText As String

    Public Sub New(text As String, buttonText As String)
        MyBase.New(text)

        Me.buttonText = buttonText
    End Sub

    Public Sub DrawNode(e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs, buttonState As PushButtonState) _
        Implements ICustomDrawTreeNode.DrawNode

        Dim font As Font = e.Node.TreeView.Font

        ' Draw Text to the left of the button
        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(
            e.Node.Bounds.Location,
            New Size(Settings.ButtonRect.Left, e.Bounds.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, font, Brushes.Black, rect, Settings.TextStringFormat)

        ' Draw the button
        rect = New Rectangle(
            e.Node.Bounds.Location + Settings.ButtonRect.Location,
            Settings.ButtonRect.Size)
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, rect, buttonText, font, True, buttonState)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It has a `Private ReadOnly buttonText As String` to store the text of the button. The normal node text and the button text are passed in the constructor of `ButtonTreeNode`:

```
Public Sub New(text As String, buttonText As String)
```

The `DrawNode` method will be called be the `CustomTreeView` in `OnDrawNode`.

---

In `CustomTreeView` I declared a `NodeButtonClick` event that will be raised when the button of a node is clicked. You can then handle this event in the form. When you select the `CustomTreeView` in the designer, this new event will appear in the "Action" section of the events.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles

Public Class CustomTreeView
    Inherits TreeView

    <Category("Action")>
    Public Event NodeButtonClick(e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs)

    Private _isButtonPressed As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText
        ShowLines = False
        FullRowSelect = True
        ItemHeight = 30
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawNode(e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs)
        Dim customDrawNode As ICustomDrawTreeNode = TryCast(e.Node, ICustomDrawTreeNode)
        If customDrawNode Is Nothing Then ' Normal text node.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, Font, Brushes.Black, e.Node.Bounds, Settings.TextStringFormat)
        Else
            customDrawNode.DrawNode(e, If(_isButtonPressed, PushButtonState.Pressed, PushButtonState.Normal))
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNodeMouseClick(e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs)
        If _isButtonPressed Then
            _isButtonPressed = False
            Refresh()
            Dim buttonNode = TryCast(e.Node, ButtonTreeNode)
            If buttonNode IsNot Nothing Then
                RaiseEvent NodeButtonClick(e)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim buttonNode = TryCast(GetNodeAt(e.Location), ButtonTreeNode)
        If buttonNode IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim btnRectAbsolute As New Rectangle(
                buttonNode.Bounds.Location + Settings.ButtonRect.Location,
                Settings.ButtonRect.Size)
            _isButtonPressed = btnRectAbsolute.Contains(e.Location)
            If _isButtonPressed Then
                Refresh()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the form you can write

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Text")
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New ButtonTreeNode("Caption", "Button"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub TreeView1_NodeButtonClick(e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) _
        Handles TreeView1.NodeButtonClick

        MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text & " clicked")
    End Sub
End Class
```

This adds a normal text node and a custom button node to the TreeView. It also handles the `NodeButtonClick` of the custom TreeView.